Problems about Probability Analysis of the Success Rate
I am currently reading a paper on linear cryptanalysis and I am a bit confused by the probability analysis of its success rate. I wonder if I can seek advice here?

Let $N$ be the number of given random plaintexts, p be the probability that equation $P[i_1,i_2,\cdots,i_a]\oplus C[j_1,j_2,\cdots,j_b]\oplus F_n(C_L,K_n)[l_1,l_2,\cdots,l_d]=K[k_1,k_2,\cdots,k_c]$ holds, and assume $|p-1/2|$ is sufficiently small. Let $q^{(i)}$ be the probability that the following equation holds for a subkey candidate $K_n^{(i)}$ and a random variable $X$: $F_n(X,K_n)[l_1,l_2,\cdots,l_d]=F_n(X,K_n^{(i)})[l_1,l_2,\cdots,l_d]$. Then if $q^{(i)}$'s are independent, the success rate of Algorithm 2 is $\int_{x=-2\sqrt{N}|p-1/2|}^{\infty}(\prod\limits_{K_n^{(i)}\ne K_n}\int_{-x-4\sqrt{N}(p-1/2)q^{(i)}}^{x+4\sqrt{N}(p-1/2)(1-q^{(i)})}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y^2/2}dy)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}dx$.

I'll try to explain the general idea. The specific content of the equation $P[i_1,i_2,\cdots,i_a]\oplus C[j_1,j_2,\cdots,j_b]\oplus F_n(C_L,K_n)[l_1,l_2,\cdots,l_d]=K[k_1,k_2,\cdots,k_c]$ may not be very important to this problem, so I will not go into detail for now.
The essence is that decoding with the correct key $K_n$ will satisfy this equation with probability $p$, whereas for an incorrect key $K_n^{(i)}$, the corresponding probability is $q^{(i)}$. We will make multiple attempts, hence the superscript $^{(i)}$.
By sampling (i.e., decoding $N$ ciphertexts), we determine whether it meets this equation. The decoded content will form a distribution, and it is believed that the distributions obtained from decoding with the correct and incorrect keys are different, which is key to calculating the accuracy. Success means that we can effectively distinguish between the distribution corresponding to the correct key and that of the incorrect key. I think the success rate is related to the magnitude of the differences between these distributions.
In my understanding, the calculation of the success rate assumes that the correct key corresponds to a distribution $N(p-1/2, \frac{1}{4N})$, but I am unsure what the distribution assumption for the incorrect key is, though I think it is something like $N(\mu^{(i)}, \frac{1}{4N})$. I also do not understand why the range of $y$ is from $-x-4\sqrt{N}(p-1/2)q^{(i)}$ to $x+4\sqrt{N}(p-1/2)(1-q^{(i)})$.
I really want to know why it is calculated this way, and if it is possible to infer the assumptions from the results and understand why $y$ takes values within this range?

cross-posted: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/111997
